# Binary subtraction using 2's compliment

Tags: binary

The question is to find the value of (31)-(37) using 2's compliment.
i convert both to binary and tyhen obtaimed the 2's compliment of 37 and then added it to the binary equivalent of 31.The answer is 11010,which is actually 26.Is i am wrong,how can this be possible?

Comment: Take the two's complement of your result.

Comment: If that wasn't enough, notice that the two's complement of `11010` is `6`. So your result is not `26`, but `-6`.

Comment: @beaker so only doing two's complement of the result will do?

Comment: Performing two's complement simply gives you an understanding of what's represented. I think you're getting tripped up because you're only using enough bits to represent your values. If you instead use a fixed size, like 8 bits (or anything larger than your values), it should be readily apparent which values are positive and which values are negative from the most significant bit.